# Aligning Equations using Multline

Tags: vertical-alignment

I am writing a simple equations with shareLatex, but cannot align them properly.

If I type like below:

```
\begin{multline}
P(t_{obs}) = &\int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1/t_{total}} P(t_{total}) d t_{total} = \int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t_{total}} \frac{1}{t_{total}^{\gamma}}d t_{total}
\\ = \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^{(1+\gamma)}}d t_{total}
= - \frac{1}{\gamma} t_{total}^{-\gamma}
\end{multline}
```

I got 
[image]

I don't know why, but P(T_obs) accompanies a new line, so it is isolated.
What I want to do is to put the first two equation in one line with P(T_obs), and the rest in the next line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm quite sure you get error messages from this input. Remove the ampersand `&`.

Comment: You shouldn't use `&`  within a `multline`.

Comment: @Bernard Oh I see. Now I am trying with Split, but If I type ' \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
    P(t_{obs})=&\int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1/t_{total}} P(t_{total}) d t_{total} = \int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t_{total}} \frac{1}{t_{total}^{\gamma}}d t_{total}\\
    &= \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^{(1+\gamma)}}d t_{total}
    = - \frac{1}{\gamma} t_{total}^{-\gamma}
    \end{split}
\end{equation} ', it still doesn't align the equations. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare the following three constructs:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\ttl}{\mathrm{total}}
\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
P(t_{\mathrm{obs}}) = \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1/t_{\ttl}} P(t_{\ttl}) d t_{\ttl} = \int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t_{\ttl}} \frac{1}{t_{\ttl}^{\gamma}}d t_{\ttl}
\\ = \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^{(1+\gamma)}}d t_{\ttl}
= - \frac{1}{\gamma} t_{\ttl}^{-\gamma}
\end{multline}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P(t_{\mathrm{obs}}) &= \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1/t_{\ttl}} P(t_{\ttl}) d t_{\ttl} = \int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t_{\ttl}} \frac{1}{t_{\ttl}^{\gamma}}d t_{\ttl}
\\ & = \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^{(1+\gamma)}}d t_{\ttl}
= - \frac{1}{\gamma} t_{\ttl}^{-\gamma}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
P(t_{\mathrm{obs}}) &= \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1/t_{\ttl}} P(t_{\ttl}) d t_{\ttl} = \int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t_{\ttl}} \frac{1}{t_{\ttl}^{\gamma}}d t_{\ttl}
\notag \\ & = \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^{(1+\gamma)}}d t_{\ttl}
= - \frac{1}{\gamma} t_{\ttl}^{-\gamma}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Choose whichever one you like best.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your input. So many possible ways are there! Can I do the same thing with Split?

Comment: `split` can also be used instead of `aligned` in the second example.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @user115534: see Gustavo's comment.

Answer (score 3):

May be you want one of these:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
  P(t_\text{obs}) = ∫_{t}^{∞} \frac{1}{1/t_\text{total}} P(t_\text{total}) d t_\text{total}\\ = ∫_{t}^{∞}\frac{1}{t_\text{total}} \frac{1}{t_\text{total}^{γ}}d t_\text{total}
  = ∫_{t}^{∞} \frac{1}{t^{(1+γ)}}d t_\text{total}
  = - \frac{1}{γ} t_\text{total}^{-γ}
\end{multline}

\begin{align}
  P(t_\text{obs}) = ∫_{t}^{∞} \frac{1}{1/t_\text{total}} P(t_\text{total}) d t_\text{total}
                                                                                                    \\ & = ∫_{t}^{∞} \frac{1}{t^{(1+γ)}}d t_\text{total}
  = - \frac{1}{γ} t_\text{total}^{-γ}
\end{align}


\begin{equation}%
  \begin{split}P(t_\text{obs}) & =∫_{t}^{∞} \frac{1}{1/t_\text{total}} P(t_\text{total}) d t_\text{total} = ∫_{t}^{∞}\frac{1}{t_\text{total}} \frac{1}{t_\text{total}^{γ}}d t_\text{total}\\ %
    &= ∫_{t}^{∞} \frac{1}{t^{(1+γ)}}d t_\text{total} = - \frac{1}{γ} t_\text{total}^{-γ}%
  \end{split}%
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I will try with your examples. By the way, in your second example with align, there is no & for the first line, but somehow the second line is aligned to the last equation in the first. Can you explain it please?

Comment: I've added a solution to you problem with `split`. Note your indices should be typed as text.

Comment: Also, if I compare my test code '\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
    P(t_{obs})=&\int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1/t_{total}} P(t_{total}) d t_{total} = \int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t_{total}} \frac{1}{t_{total}^{\gamma}}d t_{total}\\
    &=\int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^{(1+\gamma)}}d t_{total}
    = - \frac{1}{\gamma} t_{total}^{-\gamma} \bigg|_{t}^{\infty} = \frac{1}{\gamma t^{\gamma}}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}' with your split example, it seems that the only difference is that you put /text and add %. However, it seems that the alignments are different. Can you please let me know why?

Comment: Oh I see my mistake. Wrong position of &. Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. I began to have the same layout, with your code, then changed split to `aligned`, and it worked as wanted. Finally I tested  going back to split, and nothing changed. The `\text` commands have nothing to see with the problem.